# Copy azure database from one subscription to another on azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to copy database from production to development. However, they both are in different subscriptions/resource groups.

For development environment we have sql authentication and for production environment we have azure ad authentication.

Also, there sql servers are different.

So, how can I copy the database from production to development ?